# Error "conversion from string to type decimal is not Valid"

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm using Microsoft visual studio professional 2019 version 16.6.2.

I created a simple calculator using windows forms.  The calculator is supposed to allow the user to click on the number buttons as well as the buttons for the various operators and then display the result in a text box after you click on the = button. The calculator also has a decimal point to help calculate decimal number.

However I get an Error **"conversion from string to type decimal is not Valid"** whenever I try to calculate decimal numbers.

I am still a student and I don't really know much about advanced programming. If possible please try to keep your suggestions as simple as possible.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim firstNum As Decimal
    Dim secondNum As Decimal
    Dim operations As Integer
    Dim operator_Selector As Boolean = False
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "2"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "2"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "1"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "1"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "3"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "3"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "4"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "4"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "5"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "5"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "6"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "6"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "7"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "7"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "8"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "8"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "9"
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = "9"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
        If txtDisplay.Text <> "0" Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "0"

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtDisplay.Text = "0"
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPoint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPoint.Click
        If Not (txtDisplay.Text.Contains(".")) Then
            txtDisplay.Text += "."
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click
        firstNum = txtDisplay.Text
        txtDisplay.Text = "0"
        operator_Selector = True
        operations = 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEqual_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEqual.Click
        If operator_Selector = True Then
            secondNum = txtDisplay.Text

        End If

        If operations = 1 Then
            txtDisplay.Text = firstNum + secondNum
        End If

        If operations = 2 Then
            txtDisplay.Text = firstNum - secondNum
        End If

        If operations = 3 Then
            secondNum = txtDisplay.Text
            txtDisplay.Text = firstNum * secondNum
        End If



        If operations = 4 Then
            If secondNum = 0 Then
                txtDisplay.Text = "ERROR! CANNOT DIVIDE BY 0"

            Else

                txtDisplay.Text = firstNum / secondNum
            End If
        End If

        operator_Selector = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
        firstNum = txtDisplay.Text
        txtDisplay.Text = "0"
        operator_Selector = True
        operations = 2

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
        firstNum = txtDisplay.Text
        txtDisplay.Text = "0"
        operator_Selector = True
        operations = 3

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDivide_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDivide.Click
        firstNum = txtDisplay.Text
        txtDisplay.Text = "0"
        operations = 4
        operator_Selector = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can stop the debugger at the point of the exception and see what value is trying to convert. And if you turn `OPTION STRICT` on, you will suddenly see that you are doing implicit conversions to decimal, without doing any checking. Bear in mind that given the way you built this, there is no need to actually use the value in the TextBox to make the calculation, you can hold the numbers internally

Comment: You are working with strings. Things like `secondNum = 0` won't work since `secondNum` is a string. You have to convert them to `Integer` or `Decimal` first before operating on them as if they were actual numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `firstNum` and `secondNum` as `Decimal` (numbers), which is correct.

The `Text` property of textboxes is a `String`.

.NET doesn't want to automatically convert a `String` value into a `Decimal` because generally speaking that conversion is ill-defined. It depends on your culture: e.g. what's your thousand separator? It can easily fail if the string doesn't represent a number, like `"ABC"`. It can also fail or loose precision if the string contains more digits than a `Decimal` can store.

So basically, lines like `firstNum = txtDisplay.Text` and `secondNum = txtDisplay.Text` are assigning a `String` value into a `Decimal` variable and that's something the language forbids.

You'll need to use a function that performs that conversion for you.

Since you use VB.NET you can use `CDec` (stands for *Convert to Decimal*) that more or less converts anything into a `Decimal`.

```vb
firstNum = CDec(txtDisplay.Text)
```

`CDec` is specific to VB.NET though. A standard function from the Base Class Library (that you could use for example in C#) is `Decimal.Parse`, that parses a string into a decimal number. If you look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-5.0) you'll find that it can take additional parameters that control how the parsing is done (culture, number options, etc.)

```vb
firstNum = Decimal.Parse(txtDisplay.Text)
```

As a bonus tip, you could really reduce the number of click handlers if you put the number they represent on the control `Tag` property.

The first parameter `sender` in a click handler is the control that was clicked.
So assuming you put the values `"0"`, `"1"`, ... in the `Tag` property of each button, you can reuse the same click handler for all of them by doing something like `txtDisplay.Text += sender.Tag`.